Help with APEX test class failures in active Org
I'm trying to deploy an additional field into an existing aura component bundle in my production org (to improve the user interface) but keep receiving APEX test failures on the below test classes. I'm not proficient in APEX code and didn't build these test classes (I mostly work with SQL and flows), therefore I can't seem to figure out how to pass these test failures.
Please find the failed error message and code below:

CalculateexchangerateTest - System.LimitException: Too many DML rows:
10001 Stack Trace: Class.Calculateexchangerate.CalculateProductPrice:
line 20, column 1 Class.CalculateexchangerateTest.TestProduct: line
10, column 1

@isTest(seeAllData='true')
public class CalculateexchangerateTest {
    static testMethod void TestProduct()
    {
        //simular data               
        Id standardPbid = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
        Pricebook2 objPricebook2 = new Pricebook2(Name = 'price book 1',User__c=UserInfo.getUserId()); insert objPricebook2;
        Product2 objProduct1 = new Product2(Name='Product 1',Family='Boat', Capacity__c=20, Product_Price__c=50); insert objProduct1;
        Product2 objProduct2 = new Product2(Name='Product 1',Family='Boat', Capacity__c=20,Product_Price__c=50, AUD_Product__c = objProduct1.Id); insert objProduct2;
        String ProductString = Calculateexchangerate.CalculateProductPrice();
    }
}


UpdatePBTest - System.LimitException: Too many DML rows: 10001 Stack
Trace: Class.UpdatePB.UpdatePriceBook: line 49, column 1
Class.UpdatePBTest.TestProduct: line 10, column 1

@isTest(seeAllData='true')
public class UpdatePBTest {
static testMethod void TestProduct()
    { 
        //simular data               
        Id standardPbid = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
        Pricebook2 objPricebook2 = new Pricebook2(Name = 'price book 1',User__c=UserInfo.getUserId()); insert objPricebook2;
        Product2 objProduct1 = new Product2(Name='Product 1',Family='Boat', Capacity__c=20, Product_Price__c=50); insert objProduct1;
        Product2 objProduct2 = new Product2(Name='Product 1',Family='Boat', Capacity__c=20,Product_Price__c=50, AUD_Product__c = objProduct1.Id); insert objProduct2;
        String ProductString = UpdatePB.UpdatePriceBook();
    }
}

I know these test classes are failing due to bulkification, but I'm not sure how to fix this. These test classes are not available in my sandbox org (not sure how the previous developer deployed these classes). Also can't alter metadata in active org.
Any suggestions/workarounds to solve this issue are appreciated.

Hi Sophia, Too many DML rows: 10001 means the logic is inserting/updating/deleting too many records in a single transaction. It is not necessarily a bulkification problem, as you could hit the error even with a single DML call. The first thing I would try is to wrap your tested method call between Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest(), e.g.
Test.startTest();
String ProductString = Calculateexchangerate.CalculateProductPrice();
Test.stopTest();

what do those two methods do?  They appear to be updating all org data which in a testmethod is not a good idea; note, you should not need to use seeAllData=true - preferring instead to mock anything your test method needs

Thank you for your advice @FrancescoPitzalis I've updated the 2 test classes in my sandbox and attempted to deploy via a change set, however the updated classes fail due to the existing classes failing validation. Super frustrated as I seem to be going in loops. I can't delete these failing test classes from my production org either.

@cropredy CalculateexchangerateTest takes a product created in USD currency and uses the exchange rate conversion set in our org to calculate the exchange to AUD of a reciprocal related product. UpdatePBTest updates the pricebook entries created from both these products. That's my understanding of the code, but I'm not proficient in APEX code so please correct me if I'm wrong.

the method UpdatePricebook -- what does it look like?  How does it know which products to do the AUD calculations on (given there are no arguments).  Again, I'd remove the seeAllData=true so the method only examines the two mocked Products

@cropredy It does the calculations on all AUD products that were created from the reciprocal USD products every time we update the exchange rate in our production org. How do you suggest I make that change to the code, since i can't deploy the sandbox version with the changes into my production org. Should I attempt to delete the test classes and re-deploy the new versions?

Sophia -- there are so many issues here -- (1) no asserts; the testmethods don;t prove anything; (2) SeeAllData=true annotation -- this means the underlying code is probbaly looking at your entire product catalog rather than just the test method-mocked products; You should mock USD and corresponding AUD products and their pricebook entries

@cropredy Thank you, I've updated the code accordingly. How do you suggest I deploy this updated version into the production org. When I validate for deployment, the old versions fail and prevent me going live with the new versions. I cannot delete the old versions from my production org either.

you should be making the changes to the same classes; if not, you need to include in your deployment deleted classes/test classes
